# Shaka Player Embedded Widevine configuration JSON missing

Tags: ios, widevine, shaka

I've inherited a project that uses Shaka Player Embedded to play Widevine content and I want to rebuild Shaka Player to update it to the latest version. I do have the Widevine CDM files, the application works with the older version.

It seems like I'm missing the `JSON` config file referenced in this line:
`../configure --ios --eme-impl ../../WidevineCDM/shaka_plugin/dev_cdm.json --ide xcode --debug --cpu x64`

The application has been built by a third party for us and I'm simply not getting any response from Google asking for help through the official channels, for some weeks now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use old WidewineCDM project to build with Shaka player Embedded, You should ask the third party for new PreBuilt CDM project.
With that only you can use Shaka player Embedded.

Comment: Yeah the whole mystery around the Widevine CDM including crash-on-debug tricks made us step away from Widevine for iOS. Can't rely on a party that shrouds everything in mystery and hides away all documentation for something that is a standard.